# How to switch on/off ungrounded circuits using a transistor

Tags: transistors, integrated-circuit, switching

I want to switch on/off the shown parts of a circuit using a transistor, which will  controlled by an Arduino, please see the picture below - the yellow marked ones. The circuit is build around a XR2206, which is a function generator IC.

The left side controls the range the function generator is working in, by adding different capacitors between pins 5 and 6 of the XR2206.

The right side just switches between triangle or sine wave generation, by adding some resistance between pins 13 and 14 of the IC.

[image: schematic diagram]

Now, I can easily switch circuits which are connected to ground using NPN, but I fail to come up with a solution for this problem.

I am ready to accept any laughter. If I am using wrong terms etc, please give me a pointer to the right one. In the old times I would have used relays to achieve this, but I get this is too much old style and overkill for this issue here.

Comment: I didn’t  think the XR2206 was still around. But I looked up the Sparkfun 2006 EXAR datasheet and pin 12 is GND

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question - you say you can easily do it with NPNs so is it only the right hand connection you need solving?

Comment: A quad analog switch seems to solve this.

Comment: The XR2206 has been around for a long time and, to be honest, my experiences with it are not so great.  If you tell us what you exactly want to build there may be newer and better alternative which have been developed in the last 20 years.

Comment: @Andyaka: solving the connection Pins 13/14 would be a good start, yes

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75: Yep. I had a look at some datasheets. I never used them before, so I didnt even know they exist

Comment: @Oldfart: I am trying to get back into the stuff building a wafeform generator. I found a video explaining some nice features based on this chip, and it works great. However, it uses real switches for switching waveforms, ranges and so on. I want to try to control it from the Arduino, which I ran into the issues described in my question

Comment: If this is just for 'fun' that is fine. I found the waveforms coming out  rather poor and nowadays I would use an CPU to generate arbitrary waveforms. e.g. a nice 200MHz Cortex-M3 with a fast DAC can give me good waves up to 10MHz

Comment: Analog switches and Mux’s will do what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to provide the solution I found. Both marked parts of the circuit I was not able to solve by single transistors or analog switches. But opto couplers did the trick.

Thanks to all people who joined this. Appreciate your input.

PS: not saying the analog switch thing is wrong - however, I was not able to solve with the ICs I had on hand.

Comment: Optocouplers can be a good choice, especially if you use 'PhotoMOS' types which are bidirectional. Analog switches should work too, but only if the bias/control voltage is sufficient to operate them properly throughout the analog voltage range.

Answer (score 2):

When using a transistor as a switch, the "switching action" depends on the voltage between the base and emitter (or gate and source for a FET).  But in your circuit the emitter voltage is a varying analog signal.  This makes producing the correct base drive difficult.

Enter the analog multiplexer, an IC designed specifically to switch a varying analog signal with a DC control signal.  There are many to choose from, but the lower cost parts probably will not work well in your circuit.  All analog switches have an input-to-output resistance when "on", which will affect the frequency (for the capacitor switch) or waveform shape (for the tri/sine switch).  Do some reading on analog switches and multiplexers and see if they will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Seems these analogue switch ICs could solve my problem. I will give it a try.